# How does the DKIST filter out photosphere light?

Tags: sun, telescopes

How does  [DKIST](https://nso.edu/telescopes/dki-solar-telescope/) filter out light from the sun's photosphere while capturing light from the chromosphere? I'd like to know the physical or mathematical mechanics that accomplish this.

If the naive answer is as simple as "it filters for the right wavelengths", as in the photo below which apparently filters for light at exactly 486.13 nm, then please describe why such wavelengths are characteristic of the chromosphere but not the photosphere.

**The sun's chromosphere in 486.13 nm:**
[image: The sun's chromosphere in 486.13 nm]
*Image source: [National Solar Observatory](https://nso.edu/press-release/u-s-national-science-foundation-celebrates-the-inauguration-of-its-daniel-k-inouye-solar-telescope/)*

Context: A [recent press release](https://nso.edu/press-release/u-s-national-science-foundation-celebrates-the-inauguration-of-its-daniel-k-inouye-solar-telescope/) of new images from the [DKIST](https://nso.edu/telescopes/dki-solar-telescope/), as well as several derivative articles, highlight that DKIST offers new capabilities to directly image the sun's chromosphere. They note that generally or in the past the chromosphere has been difficult or impossible to image because it is drowned out by light from the photosphere, which is beneath the chromosphere. However, I cannot find any description of how DKIST accomplishes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's is not about filtering, but about the formation height of the emergent intensity throughout the solar atmosphere. In other words, the height where the sun becomes transparent depends strongly on wavelength. In general, in the continuum spectrum one sees much deeper into the sun than within wavelength range of spectral lines. (Spectral lines are more opaque than the continuum.) Some spectral lines are so opaque (*) that the light can escape from the sun only at the heights corresponding to the chromosphere. This particular image is taken at the wavelength of H-beta spectral line. It shows mixture of photosphere (granules) and chromosphere (elongated dark filaments). Lines that typically show the chromosphere are H-alpha, Ca II K&H, Mg II k&h, etc.

(*) Note that this is a bit simplified explanation. Moreover, the real question is why some lines are more opaque than others. The answer to that question is the topic of the radiative transfer theory of stellar atmospheres (see the classical books by Hubeny & Mihalas (earlier editions by Mihalas alone) or the lecture notes by Rutten.